# custom ConfigurationProperties class returning null

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following configuration class for setting custom `application.properties` properties

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("app.properties.parseaddress")
public class ParseAddressProperties {
    private String endpoint;

    public String getEndpoint() {
        return endpoint;
    }

    public void setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

}
```

In my application.properties I have

```
app.properties.parseaddress.endpoint=http://myurl.com:5000/parseAddress
```

I try to use the property in the following class

```
@Component
public class AddressParser {
    @Autowired
    ParseAddressProperties parseAddressProperties;

    public void parseAddress(String address) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        JavaHttpClient httpClient = new JavaHttpClient();
        System.out.println(parseAddressProperties.getEndpoint());
        httpClient.postRequest(parseAddressProperties.getEndpoint(), "address", address);
    }
}
```

However `parseAddressProperties.getEndpoint()` returns `null`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just copy-pasted that code within a new Spring boot project, and it works fine. Can you tell us what Spring boot version you're using?

Comment: The issue was that I was creating the AddressParser object with "new" instead of Autowired

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was creating the AddressParser object with "new" instead of Autowired

Answer (score 0):

Usually class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` is a simple POJO. 
Its registered in Configuration annotated classes. So please try the following approach:

1. Put the following line into `src/main/resources/application.properties` or `src/main/resources/config/application.properties`:

```
app.properties.parseaddress.endpoint=http://myurl.com:5000/parseAddress
```

2. Rewrite Configuration Properties class to be a POJO:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app.properties.parseaddress")
public class ParseAddressProperties {
    private String endpoint;

    public String getEndpoint() {
        return endpoint;
    }

    public void setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

}
```

3. Create a Configuration class/reuse the existing one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ParseAddressProperties.class)
public class MyConfiguration {
 ...
}
```